# How is determining body length by closing connection reliable (RFC 2616 4.4.5)

Tags: sockets, http, tcp, rfc2616

I can't get one thing straight. The [RFC 2616 in 4.4.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) states that `Message Length` can be determined "`By the server closing the connection.`".

This implies, that it is valid for a server to respond (e.g. returning a large image) with a response, that has no `Content-Length` in the header, but the client is supposed to keep fetching **till the connection is closed** and then assume all data has been downloaded.

But how is a client to know for sure that the connection was closed intentionally by the server? A server app could have crashed in the middle of sending the data and the server's OS would most likely send `FIN` packet to gracefully close the TCP connection with the client.

Comment: Why are you looking at RFC 2616, btw? What's relevant is over here: <http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#message.body.length>

Comment: Because much of the Internet still operates on RFC 2616, as 723x were standardized only 11 months ago.

Comment: @RemyLebeau -  Julian Reschke is a major authority on HTTP, so he knows what he's talking about :)The "new" RFC is not exactly a new spec, it's more of a clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely right, that mechanism is totally unreliable. This is covered in RFC 7230:

> Since there is no way to distinguish a successfully completed,
>      close-delimited message from a partially received message interrupted
>      by network failure, a server SHOULD generate encoding or
>      length-delimited messages whenever possible.  The close-delimiting
>      feature exists primarily for backwards compatibility with HTTP/1.0.

Fortunately most of HTTP traffic today are HTTP/1.1, with Content-Length or "Transfer-Encoding" to explicitly define the end of message.

The lesson is that, a message must have it own way of termination; we cannot repurpose the underlying transport layer's EOF as the message's EOF.

On that note, a (well-formed) `html` document, or a `.gif`, `.avi` etc, does define its own termination; we will know if we received an incomplete document. Therefore it is not so much of a problem to transmit it over HTTP/1.0 without Content-Length.

However, for plain text document, `javascript`, `css` etc. EOF is used to marked the end of the document, therefore it's problematic over HTTP/1.0.